# Solving $xy'+y=x^{k}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Find a solution to:
>   $$xy'+y=x^{k}$$
>   Where $k>0$, and on the assumption that the transforms of $f$ and $f'$ exist.

I understand that we can take the Laplace of all of the terms and then find the inverse Laplace transform to get a solution for $y$.

I am unsure of how to find the Laplace of the first term. 
Can someone show me how its done? It has to be using Laplace transforms !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** you can use the fact that

$$\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\} = s\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}-f(0)$$

and

$$\mathcal{L}\{tf(t)\} = -\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$$

to get that

$$\mathcal{L}\{tf'(t)\} = -\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\} = -\frac{d}{ds}\big(s\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}-f(0)\big) = - \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} - s\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$$

but you really *don't* need to resort to Laplace in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$
(xy(x))'=xy'(x)+y(x)
$$
so that your differential equation can be solved by one simple integration.

Comment: How would i solve this question using Laplace transforms to be more specific ?